# WA_DeleteOnClose delete all members?

Tags: c++, qt5, heap-memory, destructor

I'm in trouble with Qt5's `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute.

This is the situation: I have a class M that extends `QMainWindow`, and in this class I use an heap-allocated array. I read that with `WA_DeleteOnClose` when the window M is closed, and the destructor called, every member with M as parent is deleted.

My question is: what's about the array? I know that every stack-allocated member is deallocated when the destructor is called, and i know that, in normal conditions, I have to call delete[] on my array. But in these conditions? If I don't use delete[] is my array  deallocated because of the `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute?
Another question. Is the WA_DeleteOnClose attribute inherited by all M's childrens? In other words, do I have to set that attribute to true in all childrens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt will just call your destructor, it doesn't go and delete every member of your class itself!
If you have a `delete[] myArray` in your class's destructor, your array will be deleted correctly.

If you don't `delete[]` your array in the destructor, it will leak.

But better yet, don't bother managing the memory yourself, this is poor style in C++11.
Use a `QVector` or a `std::array` instead of a raw array in your class.

Comment: Thanks! With a QVector the destructor do all itself, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's called RAII.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, I have another question. Is the WA_DeleteOnClose attribute inherited by all M's childrens? In other words, do I have to set that attribute to true in all childrens?

Comment: @Pirro it's not inherited, no.

Comment: @Pirro: it's not inherited, but the parent/child mechanism ensures that when a parent gets deleted all the children gets deleted too. If you correctly parented your sub-widgets and sub-qobjects then you don't need to do anything extra, Qt will take care of their (recursive) deletion.